# Can't configure Entity Data Source to work with Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, datasource

I'm trying to use Entity Data Source Control to access my database first Entity Framework model but I can't get it to work with Entity framework 6. It gives me an error saying its not compatible with Entity Framework 6 and instead directed me to install Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource from Nuget which I've done. but for some reason I can't configure it using the wizard. In design view, it doesn't show the little arrow to open the smart tasks panel.

I'm new to ASP.NET and don't know how to configure it in markup view

which data source (or perhaps another technique) should I use to access data objects in Entity Framework 6?

Comment: Im also facing to the same issue. It says to do it manually in mark up but still not figure it out to do it. Anyway I  solved my issue using Linq table join query

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the wizard to configure EF6 EntiyDataSourceControl. The wizard only works with EF5. You need to configure the EF6 EntityDataSourceControl in code. Here is a [corresponding ticket](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2707).

Answer (score -1):

I have gone through same situation as yours.Finally this solved the issue,

Uninstalled EF6 and installed version 5 of Entity Framework through Nuget Package Manager Console, then it worked fine